# How do I know which file type was chosen from a NSSavePanel?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uti, nssavepanel

I'm writing an app on a Mavericks system.  I'm calling NSSavePanel to save a file.  I can give the panel an NSArray of UTIs to use as possible save types, and (I guess) the panel will automatically generate an output-type accessory view.  During the panel's completion block, I can use the "URL" property of the panel to get the file to (possibly create and) write.  But there seems to be no property to indicate which output type was chosen.

Am I supposed to look at the file extension of the URL?  Is this because there's an option to allow free-range extension naming?  (I don't have that option turned on here.)

*Also:* my NSArray of UTIs is a random type followed by a fixed type.  I currently add the fixed type only if it doesn't equal the random type.  Would the panel crash if I have the same UTI multiple times, or would it collapse out duplicates?  If it won't crash, then I can save time with an unconditional append.

Answer (score 0):

For the *also* question: I did an unconditional append and nothing seemed to crash.  So I guess Apple's code does collapse duplicates.

For my guess: the panel does **not** create an accessory view to choose among the multiple UTIs.  (The equivalent action on a NSDocument-oriented app does.)  The panel chooses an initial (not-so-)secret extension for the new file based on the UTI array.  If you add an extension, and it's either in the UTI list or free-range extension naming is on, the panel will allow it.  Otherwise, you get the bad-extension warning alert.  I mentioned a random type and a fixed type; 99% of the time the user would want the random type, it's chosen first, and I don't mind the fixed type needing an advanced user to trigger it (by adding its extension).

It looks like I do have to use URL's file extension to type my file.  I only have two types available, the random type is the raw data and the fixed type is one I can always generate.  And the fixed type has an easy extension so I can differentiate which data block I need to get.  I don't turn on free-range extension naming because I can't do anything with extra types.

```
/*!
    @brief Action to save a copy of the currently displayed resource.
    @param sender The object that sent this message.
 */
- (IBAction)saveDocumentTo:(id)sender
{
    NSSavePanel * const       panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    WebDataSource * const    source = self.webView.mainFrame.dataSource;
    NSURLResponse * const  response = source.response;
    NSArray * const       fileTypes = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, (__bridge CFStringRef)response.MIMEType, NULL);

    panel.allowedFileTypes = [fileTypes arrayByAddingObject:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeWebArchive];
    panel.nameFieldStringValue = response.suggestedFilename;
    panel.canSelectHiddenExtension = YES;

    [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            NSError  *error = nil;

            if (![([fileTypes firstObjectCommonWithArray:(__bridge_transfer NSArray *)UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)panel.URL.pathExtension, NULL)] ? source.data : source.webArchive.data) writeToURL:panel.URL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
                [self performSelector:@selector(showError:) withObject:error afterDelay:0.0];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

You should mostly follow what I'm doing.  The `fileTypes` object gets the array of UTIs that match the resource's MIME type.  I give the panel that array with the fixed type (Web Archive) appended.  In that last `if`, I generate the list of UTIs from the destination URL's file-extension, see if at least one UTI in the MIME and Extension arrays overlap, choose the raw source data if there's an overlap or create Web Archive data if it doesn't (i.e. the URL had the appended Web Archive's extension), and writes that data out to disk.

Note that if the original data was a Web Archive itself, it'll match the original UTI array and have its data directly dumped.  I originally had it the other way; a loaded Web Archive would be saved as an Archive of an Archive.  This bloats the file size with junk that messes up loading if you tried loading the second archive (to try a third round).  Now they're identical besides the creation dates.